# Why runBlocking doesn't block current Thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

According to [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) `runBlocking` runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until its completion. However, in the code:

```
fun main() {
    println("Before runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().state}")
    runBlocking {
        println("After runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().state}")
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Before runBlocking RUNNABLE
After runBlocking RUNNABLE
```

Why is the state of current Thread `RUNNABLE` and not `BLOCKED`?

Comment: I think "blocking" is more in context of code being sequential. JVM thread itself being still alive (and executing your suspending code block) is the point of runBlocking.

Comment: [Joao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77818168/13963086) explains it well. Also, note that `Thread.currentThread().state` _always_ returns RUNNING. The current thread _has_ to be running in order to return anything. If the current thread was blocked, it wouldn't be able to run to the point that it returns to your code. The only way you can ever see a state of BLOCKED is when you check a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition in:[Thread.State.BLOCKED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED), they mention that "Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock.". Block in the context of what they mention in [runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html), refers to a Thread being used by a coroutine, not allowing it to be used by another. In your first println you are just using the Thread directly and on the second you are performing the same operation via a coroutine on the same Thread. The thread is blocked in the sense that a coroutine is already using it but it is not blocked in the sense that it is waiting. It is not waiting, it is actually still running and this is probably why you don't get the BLOCKED state you were expecting.